# Copy all maven submodule artifacts in nexus with a classifier for branching purposes

Tags: git, maven

We have a large Maven submodule project (more than 100 submodules) which takes a while to build completely.

When a new feature is developed a feature branch is created using git and then with mvn versions:set the (temporarily) version of this feature branch is set containing the name of the feature (i.e. 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT is changed to 1.2.3-featureX-SNAPSHOT).

Then a mvn deploy is done to build the artifacts with the adapted version and upload them to Nexus so that all developers working at the feature only have to download the artifacts iso building them. (saves a lot of time)

The version name is changed so that multiple features can be developed in parallel to prevent interference between the feature teams.

The mvn deploy for the feature takes a while and this seems unnecessary since the artifacts are already build, except that the version number is not correct.

what we like to do is to copy all submodule-artifacts in Nexus with the new version iso rebuilding them.

Is there a standard way / mvn plugin which can handle this ?

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard approach to upload the same artifact with different versions. Since maven identifies an arifact to be the "same" when groud, artifact, version and classifier are equal that is plausible for the default. What you should be able to do is manually upload the artifacts with another version using the deploy plugin and the deploy-file goal: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html and changing the version parameter.

Comment: The question is simply how long does you build take to make a `mvn deploy` with a new version? And what you can save in comparison to the previous upload?

Comment: Currently we created some bash-scripting to copy the aritifacts into Nexus. The pom files within a group are searched in the local repository, versions are adapted with sed and mvn deploy:deploy-file is  used to upload the artifacts in Nexus. This does not work in all situations and we are searching for a better (maven) way  to achieve this. The progress we booked is from build times from over an hour to less than 5 minutes,